Is it possible to create a Turing machine or its analog computing algorithms on a pool table or in atomic gas mechanics?
If we have moving molecules in a gas that collide with each other or with the walls of the vessel containing them, or we have billiard balls that can also collide with each other, can we use them for computer calculations. If so, to what extent is this possible?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
